# how to change the options of select box when we change the value of other select box?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquerymobile 1.4.2.and jquery 1.11.0.

This is the html code which i am using in my page.

### HTML

```
<select name="im_g0" id="im_g0" class="ayudas" onchange="geoAdmin1=this.value,geoAdmin2=0;geoAdmin2=-1;loadgeo1Adminii1('im_g1','im_g0','g1',0);" data-mini="true" >

<option value="0">select state</option>
<option value="3001">state1</option>
<option value="3002">state2</option>
<option value="3003">state3</option>
</select>

<select name="im_g1" id="im_g1" class="ayudas" <?php if($default<=0){?> disabled="disabled"  <?php }?> data-mini="true">

</select>
```

### SCRIPT

```
 function loadgeo1Adminii1(objname,objname1,child,selected){

var gobj=AJAX_MM_findObj(objname);
var gobj1=AJAX_MM_findObj(objname1);
if(parseInt(gobj1.value,10) == 15210)
    selected = 15300;

var url=UrlServer+"index.php?im_core=xmlSearch&im_action=getSubGeoSearchAdmin&im_language="+language+"&core="+im_core;
if(gobj1.value>0){
    $('#im_'+child).css({"background-image":"url("+UrlServer+"templates/imagenes/load_blu.gif"+")","background-repeat":"no-repeat", "background-position":"90% 50%"});
    $.post(url,{im_Idgeo: gobj1.value},function(data){
        data.sort(function(a,b){
            var aName = a.Nombre.toLowerCase();
            var bName = b.Nombre.toLowerCase(); 
            return ((aName < bName) ? -1 : ((aName > bName) ? 1 : 0));
        });
        jQuery('#im_g1').html("");
        if(parseInt(gobj1.value,10) >= 30001 && parseInt(gobj1.value,10) <= 30007)

            $("#im_g1").append('<option value="0">'+'select city'+'</option>');
        else 
            $("#im_g1").append('<option value="0">'+'Ciudades'+'</option>');

        jQuery.each(data,function(i,item){
            $("#im_g1").append('<option value="'+item.idgeo+'">'+item.Nombre+'</option>');
        });
        jQuery("#im_g1").val(selected);

        $( "#im_g1" ).selectmenu( "enable" );   
        jQuery("#im_g1").focus();   
        if(selected == 15300){
            jQuery("#im_g1,#obj_g1").css('display','none');

            jQuery("#im_g1").change();

        }
        $('#im_'+child).css({"background-image":"none","background-repeat":"no-repeat", "background-position":"90% 50%"});      
    },'json');  
}else{

    $( "#im_g1" ).selectmenu( "disable" );  
        $( "#im_texto_g2" ).textinput( "disable" );
    jQuery('#im_g1').val(0);
    jQuery('#im_texto_g2').val('');
}


      }
```

If we select state1 it loads the cites which are at state1.If we select stat2 its loading city which are at state2.Everything is working fine.

The problem which i am facing is:
Assume that  we have selected a state2,in that state we have selected a city2.
But if the user went back and  selected state3(in select box),then its loading a cities based on selected state3 correctly but we will come to know this only when we click on select box(drop down list) because in second select box the selected city which its showing is still city2,
i want this to show a "select city".

Comment: I think `$("#im_g1").val(selected)` should do that.

Comment: can you provide fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to reset the 'selectedIndex` of the element when appropriate. As you're using jQuery already:

```
$('#im_g1').prop('selectedIndex',0);
```

Comment: adding your's(shennan) and Gajotres code my page is working fine:-) Thanq very much both of you.........

Answer (score 2):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lfms3/

#### HTML:

```
<div class='ui-block-a' >
    <div class='ui-body ui-body-a' style='border:0px;'>
        <div class='ui-field-contain'><label for='custCountry'>Country</label>
            <select name='custCountry' data-theme='a' id='custCountry'>
                <option  value = '1'>1</option>
                <option  value = '2'>2</option>
                <option  value = '3'>3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='ui-block-b' >
    <div class='ui-body ui-body-a' style='border:0px;'/>
    <div class='ui-field-contain'><label for='invCountry'>Country</label>
        <select name='invCountry' data-theme='a' id='invCountry'>
            <option  value = '1' selected>1</option>
            <option  value = '2'>2</option>
            <option  value = '3'>3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('change', '#custCountry', function(){ 
    $('#invCountry').val($('#custCountry option:selected').val());
    $('#invCountry').selectmenu('refresh', true);
});
```

Comment: Its working fine.I mean its not displaying old selected city(as i wanted).One more thing what i want is, it should show a "select a city" as a selected option(when we change a state).How can i do this please help me..

Comment: Then help me help you, use my jsFiddle example and add your HTML. When you do that tell me what do you need to happen when first selected box is changed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lfms3/1/.If you see this fiddle it shows initially "select a city".Like this i want each time when we change the value of first select box.Instead of showing 2 or 3 in second select box

Comment: Now tell me one thing, because I didn't understood you, what did you mean when you said : "it should show a "select a city" as a selected option(when we change a state)."?